# Why does this mysql foreign key constrain fail with are incompatible?

Tags: mysql

Hi all I have two tables and want to add a foreign key constrain in Mysql 8.12

`users` table ddl

```
create table users
(
    id   varchar(255) not null
        primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null
);
```

`user_slugs` table ddl

```
create table user_slugs
(
    id         int unsigned auto_increment         primary key,
    user_id    varchar(255)                        not null,
    locale     varchar(5)                          not null,
    slug       varchar(255)                        not null,
    constraint users_slugs_locale_slug_unique unique (locale, slug),
    constraint users_slugs_user_id_foreign foreign key (user_id) references users (id)
);

create index users_slugs_locale_index
    on users_slugs (locale);

create index users_slugs_user_id_index
    on users_slugs (user_id);

create index users_slugs_user_id_locale_index
    on users_slugs (user_id, locale);

create index users_slugs_slug_index
    on users_slugs (slug);
```

The error is

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'users_slugs_user_id_foreign' are incompatible.
```

Both user_id and the users.id are `id   varchar(255) not null` so I see no different data types!

My assumption is that this might be related to table collation somehow.

It works fine locally!!! though. These ddls are auto-generated with laravel eloquent

Update:

I checked the table collations and character sets and they are different.

users table has `utf8_unicode_ci`, and the users_slugs uses the collation: `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

Maybe this is the reason of the issue of the error.

I checked it like this `SHOW TABLE STATUS where name like 'users';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data types were the same `varchar(255) not null` and the problem was the different Collation and character set of the tables.

I solved it by assigning the same values to the users table like

```
alter table users convert to character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Then I could alter users_slugs table and add the foreign key.

I could check the character set of a table like this

```
SELECT CCSA.character_set_name FROM information_schema.`TABLES` T,
       information_schema.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` CCSA
WHERE CCSA.collation_name = T.table_collation
  AND T.table_schema = "my_database_name"
  AND T.table_name = "users";
```

and also I could check the Collation of the table like this

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS where name like 'users';
```

Once I noticed that both tables had different collation and character set I made them the same as shown above.